# mySQL get data intro an associative array

Tags: php, mysql

I am using the below code to get the users list from my db:

```
if ($result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT user_name, name, surname, avatar, user_email FROM users")) {


    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $username[]  = $row["user_name"];
        $user_email[] = $row["user_email"];
        $user_name[] = $row["name"];
        $user_surname[] = $row["surname"];
        $avatar[] = $row["avatar"];

    }

    $result->close();
}
```

But I get the below error:

> Fatal error: [] operator not supported for strings

Comment: did you initialise all those variables (`$username, $user_email, ... etc`) as arrays before using them?

Comment: mySQL get data intro an asociative array....??? what is the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably what you want to do:

```
   $rows = array();
   while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       $rows[] = $row;
   }
   // $rows is now an array that contains each individual row from your result set
```

You can then do whatever you want with that data, eg display it in a table or whatever.

```
  foreach($rows as $user)
  {
    echo $user['user_name'] . ' - ' . $user['user_email'];
  }
```

And so on

Answer (score 1):

Your $username variable has been set as a string somewhere in the code before the codeblock you have posted. If you use $username=array(); you will loose that variable. I don't know if you need it or not.

Here is a better way to do :

```
$users = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

$users[]  = array(
        "username" => $row["user_name"],
        "email"    => $row["user_email"],
        "name"     => $row["name"],
        "surname"  => $row["surname"],
        "avatar"   => $row["avatar"]
    );

}
```

And you can loop the users using foreach:

```
foreach($users as $user){
   echo $user["username"];
   echo $user["email"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should take an empty array befor loop if you want these into array. like this

```
 if ($result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT user_name, name, surname, avatar, user_email FROM users")) {

    $results=array();

        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $results []=$row;

        }

        $result->close();
    }
```

other wise you should remove `[]`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this also -

```
$user_data = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $user_data[]  = $row;
}
```

By this you can get all the data in a single array. The keys will be the same as database fields.